# Zend server troubles... Cannot connect

Tags: apache, zend-server-ce, zend-server-installation

I'm encountering troubles with WAMP so I'm giving Zend a try... I need some help getting it working though. I have Zend and Apache running... the guide says to place my files in the htdocs folder in Apache. I have my index.html in that folder and my port, in the Zend settings, is 10088. When I go to localhost:10088/index.html my browser (Chrome) cannot connect to it. What is the deal?

**EDIT:** Tried changing host name from 127.0.0.1 to localhost... no change.

Comment: Check your tags `zend-framework` has nothing to do with Zend community server

Comment: @venimus Check your response. It has nothing to do with my question.